# Binding jquery-multifile to a dynamically loaded form

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, multifile-uploader

I am using the jquery multifile plugin found here:

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

I've used it in the past and had no problems, but now I am trying to use it in a dynamically loaded form and it's causing a strange issue.

I am binding the function correctly when loading the form as per this article, so please understand this is a DIFFERENT, albeit related, problem to the one posted here:

[Cannot bind input event to jQuery multifile from dynamically loaded form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973539/cannot-bind-input-event-to-jquery-multifile-from-dynamically-loaded-form)

```
$('#reportWindow').on('click', '#continueReport', function () {
    var data = $('.reportForm').serializeObject();
    $('<div/>').load('/Forms/report.aspx', data, function () {
        doReportForm(this);
    });
});
```

An ASPX file is being loaded into a `div` using jquery `load` as per the above, the `doReportForm` function is to call in various binding methods to that dynamically generated HTML as per:

```
function doReportForm(ele) { 
    $(ele).makeModal('', 800);
    FB.XFBML.parse();
    checkLogin();
    clearNetIds($('#reportForm2'));

    $("#datePicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });

    $('[class*="toolTip"]').setupTip();
    $(".multi").MultiFile(); // input[type=file]

    $('#right').on('click', '#savePost', function () {
        var data = $('.reportForm2').serializeObject();
    });
};
```

The first line there, `$(ele).makeModal('', 800);` is simply a jQuery extension I made to create modal windows, so it as it THIS point where the element is added to the DOM, then a few lines down I bind the `MultiFile` plugin thus `$(".multi").MultiFile();`

The first time this is done, it works fine. But, when a user closes the modal window and then tries to load the form again I get an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
```

(closing the modal window removes it completely from the DOM with `jQuery.remove()`, so any future windows are written completely from fresh).

After a bit of fiddling, it appears that this is due to jQuery not being able to access the `MultiFile` script... I *think*

The `MultiFile` script is loaded in the head of the parent document, so should be available at all times.

Comment: My first guess would be that something inside the jQuery plugin fails. Did you get the development (readable) source? `.apply` is likely called on a function, why is it `undefined`?

Comment: yes, `.apply` is called 4 times in the plugin, but I can't see why anything should be undefined second time round.

Comment: Couldn't crack this, whatever I do, if I rebind this plugin without a page load it causes errors. I had to re-work my workflow to avoid any need to rebind.

Comment: What do you mean by 'rebind'? Are you loading that plugin twice?

Comment: No, but each time I load my modal window I was creating new elements to which the function needs to bind `$(".multi").MultiFile();` is called. Calling this on new elements a second time causes the error. So I am now only generating the elements with JQuery once and then hiding, rather than removing them from the page when closed.